# IIS-Rewrite - How to filter and remove #attribute from the url

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

I am writing the redirect rule for redirecting the old domain url http://old.domain.com/promotions#all-views to
http://new.domain.com/en-us/promotions/all

I have tried multiple options but could achieve the above redirection, here mentioned the sample rule used for this,

```
<rule name="Redirection for promotions" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^promotions$" />
    <conditions>
      <!--  <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="all-views" /> -->
      <!--  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="#all-views$" /> -->      
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://new.domain.com/en-us/promotions/all" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Issue 1 :
Couldn't match the url pattern "#all-views", server variables are not providing this data, I have validated with HTTP_URL, REQUEST_URI, URI, QUERY_STRING

Issue 2 :
"#all-views" always appended with the redirected url like, http://new.domain.com/en-us/promotions/all#all-views, how to remove the #all-views?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the rule below:

```
<rule name="test1" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$" />
       <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^old.domain.com$" />
       </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://new.domain.com/en-us/promotions/all" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, its for redirecting the old domain to new domain. I have challenge in handling the #attribute of the old domain.

Comment: What challenge have you got? In redirects, you don’t need #attribute in the old domain. What is your purpose?